# How can I get httparse to parse my request correctly?

Tags: rust

Ive got an api set up by using a TcpListener, and when trying to parse the headers from the request data with httparse it only returns `Err(HeaderName)`. I have also checked and I can confirm with printing the request data that I get a full request.

```rust
fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:2352").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        handle_connection(stream);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    let mut headers = [httparse::EMPTY_HEADER; 4];
    let parsed_headers = httparse::parse_headers(&buffer, &mut headers);

    let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";

    stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
    println!("Request Headers: {:?}", parsed_headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`httparse::parse_headers()`](https://docs.rs/httparse/1.5.1/httparse/fn.parse_headers.html) only parses HTTP headers, *not* the full HTTP request. It expects that the buffer you pass in *only* contains headers and the body. In other words, the `parse_headers()` function expects something like this:

```
Header1: Value1
Header2: Value2
Header3: Value3

This is the body.
```

But a full HTTP request looks something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Header1: Value1
Header2: Value2
Header3: Value3
```

That's what trips it up.

To parse a full request, you should use the [`httparse::Request`](https://docs.rs/httparse/1.5.1/httparse/struct.Request.html) struct, like so:

```rust
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    let mut headers = [httparse::EMPTY_HEADER; 4];
    let mut req = httparse::Request::new(&mut headers);
    let res = req.parse(&buffer).unwrap();

    // Here, ``res`` is an Err() if something went wrong, and Ok otherwise.
    // The ``req`` variable contains the request properties, and
    // the ``headers`` variable contains the headers.
}
```

Comment: How to get the query params for GET and body for POST?